# How can i install .deb package that i built?

Tags: python, deb

I'm new at Ubuntu. I built my program as `.deb` (There were two scripts). I couldn't open it. I installed it from Ubuntu Software because  I don't know how to install via terminal. It doesn't seem to be a program in my computer. So, what should I do?

I tried to run my package with "dpkg -i" like below:

```
(Reading database ... 204097 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack py2executable_v0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking py2executable (0.1) over (0.1) ...
Setting up py2executable (0.1) ...
```

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Did you make sure to compile it correctly?

Comment: I am running with Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: I installed it with dpkg but still can't see it.

Answer (score 7):

1. `.deb` installation packages can be installed with the `apt` tool as

   ```
    sudo apt install path/to/the/file.deb
   ```

   This automatically will pull in required dependencies. Since you know how to prepare `.deb` packages, you will probably know that, for your package to be installable, the dependencies you require should mach these provided by the base system of the particular Ubuntu version for which you make the package.
2. Another way to install `.deb` packages is the lower-level tool `dpkg -`, followed by a `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix missing dependencies if any:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i path/to/the/file.deb
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
3. A simple graphical tool to install `.deb` packages is `gdebi`, available in the software sources.

Comment: For the approach 2 it works with `sudo apt install -f` too